# <route-list/> in Vue application?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, routes

I maintain a web application built on VueJS+Vuetify with some AngularJS. There is a tag in a .vue file I have never seen before and cannot find any documentation on **anywhere:** **`<route-list/>`**

Code:

`<route-list v-bind:routes="computedData" />`

From what I can tell it binds a list of routes into a side bar navigation based on a computed function.

Is this some kind of depreciated Vue tag? I can't find anything on this tag whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it is not your own plugin?

`Vue.use (<plugin>);`

See more details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin